# PreparedStatement not handling q[] quoted string

Tags: java, sql, oracle, prepared-statement

Consider following PreparedStatement,

```
String sql = "select ID from Test_Table where value = q'[?]'";
PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

statement.setObject(1, "testValue");
```

In above code, setObject call is failing with following exception.
`java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index`

I can not remove `q[]` from sql, I am getting it from user input.

Any solutions how to use PreparedStatement with `q[]`?

Comment: Why not `value = ?`? That should do the quotes and escaping by the PreparedStatement itself.

Comment: I know PreparedStatement handles SQL literals, but as I mentioned I am getting sql string from user input. I can not modify it.

Comment: So no `sql = sql.replaceAll("\\bq'\\[\\?\\]", "?")`?

Comment: Is this the only solution ? PreparedStatement don't support `q[]` ?

Comment: Do not take my word for it, but I doubt it.

Comment: It's nonsense. `q'[dfdsfsfdsf'''fdfsdfs']'` is so called Perl-style quoted string. So your query has NO bind variables. So what exactly do you want to achieve. Simply user sql.replace('?', textValue); If you're not scared of SQL injection.

Comment: I am scared of SQL injection...what I want to achieve is support `q[]` with PreparedStatement.

Comment: `q[]` is special form of quoted string. so the query `select ID from Test_Table where value = q'[?]'` can be safely executed. It will return all the rows where test_table.value equals to '?'. That's all. This query simply has no bind variable parameters.

Comment: The query is identical to `select ID from Test_Table where value = '?'`.

Comment: Why do you think you need to do the `q` quoting though? If you bind the user-supplied value as a string it doesn't matter if it contains single quotes, you don't have to escape or handle those. Which is what JoopEggen said in the first comment, really.

Comment: I know we don't need to handle when we bind the values, but user is giving whole query as input not only variable values. Thats what I said in second comment :)

Comment: If they are giving you that string containing `q'[?]'` then *they* are trying to use a literal question mark, and there is nothing for you to bind against. If that isn't what they actually meant, they are giving you a malformed string and you can't make them do something different, then you will have to strip out the broken quoting, as per the third comment. The prepared statement is doing exactly what it is supposed to do. Your SQL string has a quoted string literal, it would be *wrong* for it to try to treat it as a bind variable. You have to fudge it into the correct form.

Comment: makes sense Alex...thanks :)